# Transforming MPSNNImageNode using Metal Performance Shader

Tags: ios, neural-network, swift4, yolo, metal-performance-shaders

I am currently working on replicating YOLOv2 (not tiny) on iOS (Swift4) using MPS.

A problem is that it is hard for me to implement space_to_depth function (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/space_to_depth) and concatenation of two results from convolutions (13x13x256 + 13x13x1024 -> 13x13x1280). Could you give me some advice on making these parts? My codes are below.

```
...



let conv19 = MPSCNNConvolutionNode(source: conv18.resultImage,

                                 weights: DataSource("conv19", 3, 3, 1024, 1024))



let conv20 = MPSCNNConvolutionNode(source: conv19.resultImage,

                                 weights: DataSource("conv20", 3, 3, 1024, 1024))



let conv21 = MPSCNNConvolutionNode(source: conv13.resultImage,

                                 weights: DataSource("conv21", 1, 1, 512, 64))



/*****

    1. space_to_depth with conv21

    2. concatenate the result of conv20(13x13x1024) to the result of 1 (13x13x256)

    I need your help to implement this part!

******/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I believe `space_to_depth` can be expressed in form of a convolution:
   For instance, for an input with dimension `[1,2,2,1]`, Use 4 convolution kernels that each output one number to one channel, ie. `[[1,0],[0,0]] [[0,1],[0,0]] [[0,0],[1,0]] [[0,0],[0,1]]`, this should put all input numbers from spatial dimension to depth dimension.
2. MPS actually has a concat node. See here: [https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metalperformanceshaders/mpsnnconcatenationnode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metalperformanceshaders/mpsnnconcatenationnode%5C)

   You can use it like this:
   `concatNode = [[MPSNNConcatenationNode alloc] initWithSources:@[layerA.resultImage, layerB.resultImage]];`

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with the high level interface and the MPSNNGraph, you should just use a MPSNNConcatenationNode, as described by Tianyu Liu above.

If you are working with the low level interface, manhandling the MPSKernels around yourself, then this is done by:

1. Create a 1280 channel destination image to hold the result
2. Run the first filter as normal to produce the first 256 channels of the result
3. Run the second filter to produce the remaining channels, with the destinationFeatureChannelOffset set to 256.

That should be enough in all cases, except when the data is not the product of a MPSKernel. In that case, you'll need to copy it in yourself or use something like a linear neuron (a=1,b=0) to do it.